# Export all AD attributes and default "Range Upper" size for the User class?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I need to write approximately 1000 - 5000  characters into a user property, but I'd prefer not to edit the schema rangeUpper attribute, or create one just for my purposes.

How should I research what user attributes I could repurpose for this?  In other words, how can I export all properties available to an AD user and the corresponding rangeUpper value?

Comment: Out of curiosity what would you use a 5000 character field on a user for?

Comment: what are you trying to do shove "war and peace" into a users object?

Comment: @tonyroth The `thumbnailPhoto` attribute of my user object is a bit over 6200 [hex] characters.  Does this count?  It think OP's answer to Jim's question may help us understand.

Comment: What I've seen before is that somebody was putting text into a user attribute that could have be more efficiently coded as a bitmap (don't confuse this with a graphic bitmap). In this one particular case he was putting in about 3000+ characters into each users attribute fields, I recoded it as a bitmap that took 9 bytes yet still contained the same info.  Admittedly this was a stupid case but the idea is/was the same.

Comment: Reason for 5000 characters: The developers keep changing their idea on the schema since that is a non reversible change, we are asking them to write to a single value.  The length is high because they are serializing the objects as XML strings and sticking it into AD.

Comment: damn developers, not knowing what the developers are storing within the serialized objects means that its nearly impossible to improve the situation.

Comment: It also just plain sounds like a bad idea.  Finalize the schema then figure out how best to store it.  There are likely to be fields that already exist to handle the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following PowerShell will look at the schema's [user class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683980(v=vs.85).aspx), grab its [`allowedAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675217(v=vs.85).aspx) attribute, then look up the definition of each attribute and return its [`rangeUpper`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679438(v=vs.85).aspx) value.

```
# Need the Microsoft AD PS module
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

# Get the user class definition, include "allowedAttributes"
$userClass = Get-ADObject -SearchBase ((Get-ADRootDSE).schemaNamingContext) -Filter { Name -eq "User" } -Properties allowedAttributes

# Walk the allowedAttributes array and sort into a table with "name" and "rangeUpper"
$userClass.allowedAttributes | 
  ForEach-Object { Get-ADObject -SearchBase ((Get-ADRootDSE).schemaNamingContext) -Filter { LDAPDisplayName -eq $_ } -Property rangeUpper } |
    Sort-Object Name |
      Format-Table -Property Name, rangeUpper

# If you want to only see defined "rangeUpper" values
$userClass.allowedAttributes | 
  ForEach-Object { Get-ADObject -SearchBase ((Get-ADRootDSE).schemaNamingContext) -Filter { LDAPDisplayName -eq $_ } -Property rangeUpper } |
    Where-Object { $_.rangeUpper } |
      Sort-Object Name |
         Format-Table -Property Name, rangeUpper
```

Comment: This is fantastic!  I don't see custom attribute #14 there, so perhaps that is implemented somewhere else?  Or perhaps it is "Extension-Name"?

Comment: @makerofthings7 [`ExtensionName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675673(v=vs.85).aspx) is defined by the default AD schema.  I suspect your `custom attribute #14` has been added by a developer.  Can you provide more details [edit your question] about this custom attribute? May need to poke some info/properties from it to determine how to proceed.

Comment: Sure these custom attributes are added by Exchange and I think several of them are added during the default AD install.  There are Custom Attributes 1 through 15.

Comment: @makerofthings7 Are you referring to [`ms-Exch-Extension-Attribute-14`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms980479(v=exchg.65).aspx) from the class [`ms-Exch-Custom-Attributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa484961(v=exchg.65).aspx). Don't have Exchange, but let me test some things...

Comment: I'd tend to shy away from any of the attributes named "ms-..."  unless you know exactly why they are there and what they are used for.

Comment: @makerofthings7 FWIW, all the `ms-Exh-Extention-Attribute-[1-15]` attributes have either 1024 or 2048 in `rangeUpper` according to the docs.